# Error 80004005 when trying to uninstall Hyper-V on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

So I'm pretty sure that there's no easy answer to this one but I'll give it a shot anyways. I installed Hyper-V the other day and now that I'm trying to use it, the MMC snap-in won't even load.

So I figured I'd just remove and reinstall it except when I try to remove it, I get an error 0x80004005. Using dsim from the command line produces the same result. An online search returned nothing relevant.

Now the twist is that I may have installed Hyper-V before I moved my hard drive to a different computer, frankly I don't remember if I installed it before or after. In any case I moved from an older Intel Core2 Duo system to am AMD FX 8120 so that's quite a difference in architecture. Yet Windows handled it pretty well, except for this issue.

I'd appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: 0x80004005 is an Access Denied error. usually that means you either need to run the program as an administrator, or that a file the program is attempting to write to has a write-lock established by another program. you can try elevating, adjusting permissions on the file, or rebooting to deal with these issues in most cases.

Comment: no, 0x80004005 = generic fail. You mean 0x80007005. @Ventajou copy the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS to the desktop, zip that folder and upload the zip (Skydrive, dropbox) and insert a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and did a "Refresh" of Windows 8. Kept my files, lost my programs but at least Hyper-V works now.